# Multiplexer that works by measuring voltage on select input?

Tags: arduino, multiplexer

Is there any small MUX device that would provide 8-64 inputs, which reads from a single select input?

I'm thinking that instead of using e.g. 3 select inputs to set which signal input to use, such a device might read a single input and select based on PWM or on voltage.

Thus, an Arduino user could use a single selector pin to configure which input is read from.

Comment: You're saying "mutex" but I think maybe you mean multiplexer or "mux"?

Comment: The arduino's "analog outputs" don't work like that, unless they changed it in a recent revision.

Comment: What is going to happen when your control voltage is between two valid values? Or, when the PWM is between 2 valid duty cycles?

Comment: A serially driven mux springs to mind

Comment: _"Is there any small MUX device that would provide 8-64 inputs, which reads from a single select input?"_ Not that I am aware of. What type of input do you want to multiplex?

Comment: @LiorBilia w.l.o.g. these corner cases can be avoided through *ADC without missing codes* (basically all modern ADC components don't have that problem).

Comment: An analog decoder from a Voltage or duty cycle to a parallel digital address value to select an analog input adds significant overhead in chip real estate with comparators and resistor ladders.   The more direct approach with a serial data stream to select a channel makes more sense.  A Cortex has 46 ports

Comment: @Hearth: I believe that the Arduino Uno analog pins do in fact output a PWM signal. But even if they don't, the 3, 9, 10, and 11 digital pins do.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like another XY-problem. I doubt you can find a mux with this many channels that can be controlled by single wire. Nevertheless, here are some ideas for you.

Ideally, I'd recommend using something like serially controlled [ADG731](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG725_731.pdf) mux, which requires only 3 pins. However, if you carefully time SYNC signal and supply external clock, you can get by with 2 wires only, thanks to internal 8-bit counter that will automatically stop accepting input after 8 clock ticks.

If you insist on single wire control, you can do it with 2 chips. One is MUX with parallel address input, another is binary counter. For example combination of [ADG706](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG706_707.pdf) and [SN74LS93](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls93.pdf) will give you *sequential* access to 16 analog channels.

Comment: Thank you.‎‎‎‎‎‎ ִּּ